# No me muestra los datos de Firebase

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, recyclerview

estoy realizando una aplicación en Android Studio con Java, y quiero que en ella se escriban datos en firebase los cuales luego poder mostrarlos, a la hora de escribir no tengo problema, pero a la hora de visualizar no consigo que los muestre en el recyclerview, y me estoy volviendo loco porque no me da error ni nada. Dejo aquí las clases y como lo tengo hecho por si alguien me puede ayudar. Gracias.

Clase userPojo:

```
public class userPojo {

private String tipo;
private String titulo;
private String avance;
private String plataforma;
private String uid;

public userPojo() {

}

public String getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public void setTipo(String tipo) {
    this.tipo = tipo;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getTitulo() {

    return titulo;
}

public void setTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public String getAvance() {
    return avance;
}

public void setAvance (String avance) {
    this.avance = avance;
}



public String getPlataforma() {
    return plataforma;
}

public void setPlataforma(String plataforma) {
    this.plataforma = plataforma;
}}
```

Clase Adapter:

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.userpojoviewholder>  {

    List<userPojo> datos;
    public Adapter(List<userPojo> datos){
        this.datos=datos;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public userpojoviewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler, 
    parent,false);
    userpojoviewholder holder= new userpojoviewholder(v);
    return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull userpojoviewholder holder, int position) {
        userPojo userpojo = datos.get(position);
        holder.textViewTipo.setText(userpojo.getTipo());
        holder.textViewTitulo.setText(userpojo.getTitulo());
        holder.textViewAvance.setText(userpojo.getAvance());
        holder.textViewPlataforma.setText(userpojo.getPlataforma());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
       return datos.size();
    }

    public static class userpojoviewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textViewTitulo, textViewTipo,textViewAvance, textViewPlataforma;
         public userpojoviewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textViewTipo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewtipo);
             textViewTitulo=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewtitulo);
             textViewAvance=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewavance);
             textViewPlataforma=itemView.findViewById(R.id.textviewplataforma);
        }
    }
 }
```

Y la clase visualizar:

```
       public class Visualizar extends AppCompatActivity {
List<userPojo> datos;
Adapter adapter;
 RecyclerView rv;
 String userid;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizar);
    int nightModeFlags = this.getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
    switch (nightModeFlags) {
        case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES:
            /* si esta activo el modo oscuro lo desactiva */
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
            break;
    /*    case Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO:
            /* si esta desactivado el modo oscuro lo activa */
           /* AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(
                    AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
            break; */
    }
   userid= FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid();
    rv=  findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    datos=new ArrayList<>();

    FirebaseDatabase database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://proyecto-daniel-sanchez-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app");

    adapter=new Adapter(datos);
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);
    database.getReference().getRoot().addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot datasnapshot) {
            datos.removeAll(datos);
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : datasnapshot.getChildren() ){
                userPojo user= snapshot.getValue(userPojo.class);
                datos.add(user);

            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });




    }
}
```

Y esto es firebase

[image: y esto es firebase]

A la hora de ejecutar la clase visualizar arranca pero el recycler view está vacío, y no sé donde está el fallo, gracias de antemano.

Impresión de error en `LogCat`:

> > The specified message queue synchronization barrier token has not been posted or has already been removed 13555-13555/com.example.proyectofinaldanielsanchez D/ViewRootImpl[Archivos]: windowFocusChanged hasFocus=false inTouchMode=true 13555-13555/com.example.proyectofinaldanielsanchez W/Choreographer: Already have a pending vsync event. There should only be one at a time. 13555-13555/com.example.proyectofinaldanielsanchez D/DecorView: onWindowFocusChangedFromViewRoot hasFocus: true, DecorView@b99251b[Visualizar]

Comment: ¿Y qué te sale en el `LogCat`?

Comment: En primer lugar remueve esto  datos.removeAll(datos); y luego nos dices que tal

Comment: Bueno, ya lo solucioné, luego subo la respuesta correcta por si a alguien le viene bien, gracias!